# Today's Custom Post Query in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I use given below post query in my template. But all post of "live-sports-items" are shown in the template. I want just Today's post. What can i do now??

```
<blink>
    $today = getdate();
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'  => -1,
        'post_type'=> 'live-sports-items',
        'date_query' => array(
            array(
                'year'  => $today['year'],
                'month' => $today['mon'],
                'day'   => $today['mday'],
            ),
        ),
    );

    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();?>
        <li><?php the_title(); ?> <br /></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</blink>
```

Answer (score 0):

EDITED:

try to change

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'  => -1,
    'post_type'=> 'live-sports-items',
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'year'  => $today['year'],
            'month' => $today['mon'],
            'day'   => $today['mday'],
        ),
    ),
);
```

with

```
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page'  => -1,
  'post_type'=> 'live-sports-items',
  'year'  => $today['year'],
  'monthnum' => $today['mon'],
  'day'   => $today['mday'],
);
```

:-) Let me know if it helps.

Comment: A few moments ago I've edited the code above. Which changes you have made?

Comment: Which Wordpress version u use?

Comment: I've tested your code into my wordpress installation and it works. The reason why it doesn't works to you probably is 'cause there are no today's posts or post_type "live-sports-items" is incorrect.
However you can try to pass variables directly inside WP_Query.

Example:
    $query = new WP_Query( 'year=2014&monthnum=11&day=29' );